# Where to put custom PHP and JQuery code on Wordpress?

Tags: php, jquery, wordpress, youtube

I am really new to Wordpress but not to web development.

I am creating a wordpress based website, I have a youtube channel with more than 450 videos, and I would like to create a post for each one of them.

I already have an API KEY for Youtube API Data V3 and the right url to bring my videos. Also, I read about this great [wp_insert_post](https://developer.wordpress.org/reference/functions/wp_insert_post/) that seems to do exactly what I need to do.

What I want to know is **where to put my code**? It will be very simple, something like:
Clientside:

```
$.get('https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=50&playlistId=UUbRrCTEldKci2yWosUukSQQ&key=APIKEY');
.success(function(data){
    data.forEach(function(vid){
        $.post('myPhpPostInserter.php', vid);
    });
});
```

Server Side:

```
<?php
$myPost['title'] = $_POST['vid_title'];
//some more mapping on the $myPost array...
wp_insert_post($myPost);
```

This will be a one-time job, so I am trying to implement this quick client-server solution.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

the usual place is in functions.php in your theme or child theme (recommended as updates will overwrite custom code in your theme) or a plugin you create yourself (pluginname.php).

I have put the best way to achieve this below, its not client side at all but I believe this will suit you better. Basically on every page load the code will run and upload the next 50 videos (if timing out reduce the figure below -- see comments) (you should remove the code when all videos are uploaded).

Also excuse me if there are any errors, typed this out on a txt file. Also i dont know the structure of the json returned, i dont have a api key to check, you will need to update the correct structure in the for loop to get the data you want...

```
function upload_videos(){


    if(!get_option( 'vid_count' ) ){
        $x=0;
        update_option( 'vid_count', $x );
    } else {
        $x= (int) get_option('vid_count');
    }

    //might as well cache the file to speed things up
    if( !file_exists ( 'videos.json' )){

        $ch = curl_init();
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_SSL_VERIFYPEER, false);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, true);
        curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://www.googleapis.com/youtube/v3/playlistItems?part=snippet&maxResults=5000&playlistId=UUbRrCTEldKci2yWosUukSQQ&key=APIKEY');
        $json = curl_exec($ch);
        curl_close($ch);

        $videos = fopen("videos.json", "w") or die("Unable to open file!");
        fwrite($videos, $json);
        fclose($videos);
        unset($videos);
    }

    $videos =  fopen("videos.json", "r");
    $videos = json_decode($videos);


    //get the structure of the array here and update the foreach loop to the right place in the object...
    //remove this code when ready.....
    var_dump($videos);
    exit;
    //end remove.....


    /*
        remember to update to the correct values....
        we will do 50 at a time
    */
    $max= $x+50; // adjust 50 downwards if needed

    if($max > count( $videos['list'] ) )
        $max= count( $videos['list'] );

    if($max > $x)
        return;


    update_option('vid_count', $max );

    for($v=$x; $v<=$max; $v++){

        $id= wp_insert_post(
        array(
            'post_status'=>'publish',
            'post_type'=>'video', //higher recommended to create a cpt and post template for this..
            'post_title'=> $videos['list'][$v]->title, // sample --- dont know the format of the returned object
            'content'=> 'whatever you want or html for the video, etc................'
        ));

        //save the url into the metadata of the post....we can use this in templates to show the video....
        update_post_meta($id, '_vid_url', $videos['list'][$v]->video_url);// sample --- dont know the format of the returned object

    }

}

add_action('init', 'upload_videos');
```

Comment: Thanks! really helpful and complete answer. Btw, on V3 we have acces to the nextPageToken property for pagination effects.

Comment: im not too sure what you mean, the code reads the entire json output. If you want you can save the token into postmeta, but it wont be relevant to wp, which is ok because wp does pagination on post lists. Are you accepting this answer or is there something i have missed?